# sed's greedy match shouldn't match this string, but does

Tags: sed, regular-expression

From what I've read online, it's hard to understand the behaviour of a non-greedy match (lazy match) in `sed`.  I am puzzled by what seems to be a lazy match.

In `~/tmp/tmp.txt`, I have one line with 3 alphanumeric strings separated by 2 tabs: `TheQuick<TAB>BrownFox<TAB>JumpedOver`.  If I issue `sed -n -E '/^.+\t.+\t.+$/p' ~/tmp/tmp.txt`, the line prints out.

It seems to me like it shouldn't because even though the regular expression matches 3 strings separated by 2 tabs, the strings are not alphanumeric.  So the first string should greedily gobble up all the characters on the line, leaving nothing to match the first tab.

How can I understand this behaviour so that I can craft reliable regular expressions?  I am using GNU `sed`.

Comment: It does this by repeated *backtracking* I think - see for example [In regular expressions, what is a backtracking / back referencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011951/4440445) and also [Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: So it's not intended behaviour according to the documentation?  That means it's hard to use the documented intended behaviour to craft regular expressions.

Comment: No, it is entirely intended behavior.

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer but I think I might not quite understand what is confusing you. Could you clarify why "alphanumeric" is relevant here? Did you think that `.` only matches alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @terdon that's what I thought at first too but now I think the OP is confused that the regexp `.+\t` can match `anything\t` because they think that `.+` should match the whole line and so how could it match `\t` in the input when in their mind the `\t` should be consumed by the `.+`. All the stuff about "alphanumeric" in the question is IMHO just a red herring and it's just "how can `.+X` match `fooX` when `.+` alone matches `fooX`"?.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, that's how I answered, explaining that it's the entire regex that needs to match, not just a part of it.

Comment: For the OP - you may find this article useful as it describes at a high level how BRE and ERE (i.e. non-greedy) leftmost-longest matching works: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax_leftmost_longest.html.

Comment: I read steeldriver's two links, and Ed Morton's link.  There's a *lot* more the regex processing than I imagined.  I thought that it tries to fulfill each group from left to right, and was not aware of backtracking.  Thank you for that.  I may never fully get all the ways that a regex engine may try to satisfy the expression, but I know it's a lot more capable than I was assuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A greedy matching system just means it will try to find the largest *matching* string (meaning the *first* largest, it will stop searching at the first match for the whole regex), not that it will stop at a non-matching string even if matching strings exist. Think of it as the order to "find me the largest possible match, but do find me a match!". Since allowing the first `.\+` to eat up the entire string would mean that the regex doesn't match, the engine will go back and try something else.

In your case, it is even simpler since you are anchoring the regex to the beginning and end of the line (`^` and `$`), so the `.+` can never reach the end of the line because there are other things in the regular expression after it.

Here's an example that might help explain greedy matching:

```
$ echo aaaaaaa | sed 's/a*/B/'
B
```

Here, since the regular expression `a*` means "match 0 or more consecutive `a` characters", the greedy match will find the largest possible *matching* string. A non-greedy match, using PCRE for example, would return:

```
$ echo aaaaaaa | perl -pe 's/a*?/B/'
Baaaaaaa
```

That's because non-greedy will find the shortest matching string instead of the longest.

I don't understand why you mention alphanumeric or how that is relevant. Perhaps you have misunderstood `.` and think that only matches alphanumeric strings, but it doesn't; `.` will match everything (depending on which flavor of regular expressions you are using and what options you give it, it can even match newline characters). If you want alphanumeric strings, you can use the POSIX character class `[[:alnum:]]` which matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: I referred to alphanumeric because I wanted to emphasize my visualization of the regex engine as not confining a dot to an alphanumeric character, wherein lies the problem, as I mistakenly pictured it.  Thank you for dispelling that wrong picture.

Comment: Clarification: a greedy match finds the largest match *among those starting closest to the beginning of the region*, not necessarily the largest overall.  So ` sed 's/a*/B/' <<<'aaayaaaaa'` prints `Byaaaaa`, not `aaayB`.

Comment: You may want to mention perl's `*+` one that matches as much as possible and doesn't give anything back which would match what the OP was thinking greedy matching does